# To select any date in datepicker and should highlight current date

Tags: c#

In the below code i have a datepicker it shows the current date if i want to select another date it is not allowing me to select.But My aim is to select any date from date picker and calendar should highlight the current date.Pls help me to solve the issue.
C#

```
 dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Dont assign today date , then you will be able to pick a date from the date picker.

Comment: Check http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html

Comment: Is this ASP.Net/Windows form/WPF/something else?

Comment: It is Windows form C#

Comment: @user3319384: can you show how it is showing now? sample snapshot?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/C-Sharp-datetimepicker-control/